# I am trying to call a distance method in a Point class but it is returning Type Error: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python

I am trying to call the distance method on point class but it is returning a type error.

```
from math import sqrt

class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self,other):
        return Point(self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y)

    def distance(self, other):
        return Point(sqrt((self.x-other.x)**2+(self.y-other.y)**2))
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(%d,%d)"%(self.x,self.y)

    points=Point(6,9)
    point1=Point(3,18)
    print(points.distance(point1))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Can you fix the indendation in the code so we can run it? Also, add the full traceback so we can see the entire message, which line failed, and the call stack.

Comment: The problem is in the definition of the `distance` method. Why do you think this should return a `Point`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond - instead of just taking swipes at OP, why not point out what the problem is?

Comment: In your model, "distance" is a scalar value, not a `Point`.

Comment: @tdelaney not sure why you think I was "taking swipes". I thought I was indeed pointing out the source of the problem, as well as asking why they wanted to return a `Point` instance (which is what is causing the error, and seems very odd to me, but it's hard to tell the precise intention, hence my question).

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
    def distance(self, other):
        return Point(sqrt((self.x-other.x)**2+(self.y-other.y)**2))
```

You are calculating the distance (scalar value), yet trying to return a `Point`.  It should be:

```
    def distance(self, other):
        return sqrt((self.x-other.x)**2+(self.y-other.y)**2)
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your correction it has worked now

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code is the erroneous one. You are passing only one argument to class `Point`:

```
    def distance(self, other):
        return Point(sqrt((self.x-other.x)**2+(self.y-other.y)**2))
```

You should also return a value not a class

Answer (score 0):

In the distance method you are passing a single argument to Point()".

```
Point(sqrt((self.x-other.x)**2+(self.y-other.y)**2))
```

There is something fundamentally wrong about your code, the distance is not a Point, it's a value, so you don't want to create a Point() to return a value, you simply need to return sqrt((self.x-other.x)**2+(self.y-other.y)**2) .